# Android Studio - Button Widget OnClick. Cannot find function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick

I want `myButton` to execute a function when clicked, I have tried this method as it has worked for me from another project, but I am missing or doing something wrong here as it is not working.

I have a button on my XML file with the ID `VazhdoButoni`, and I have a `public gogogo (View v) {` on my java.

When I go to my XML file and at my button properties, at the `onClick` choose box, I don't see my `public gogogo` function there.
The class is:

```
public class BikeFragment extends Fragment {
```

The View is:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bike, container, false);
}
```

Java code:

```
public void gogogo (View v) {

    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.teksti2);
    username = ((EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.user2)).getText().toString();
    password = ((EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.pass2)).getText().toString();
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        // System.out.println("Database connection success.");

        String result = "Database connection success\n";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from tblItems");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        while(rs.next()) {
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
            result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";

        }
        tv.setText(result);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

xml button:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Vazhdo"
    android:id="@+id/VazhdoButoni"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="340dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />
```

Comment: I´m a little bit confused about Your code...but if I understand You the right way and You want to execute gogogo, You have to set the attribute in Your xml for button: android:onClick="gogogo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed onClick tag

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Vazhdo"
    android:id="@+id/VazhdoButoni"
    android:onClick="gogogo"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="340dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />
```

Comment: Hey Nilesh, thanks for answer. It builds without a error but when I try it on bluestacks I get so result, also on Android Studio at "gogogo" function I see a message "Method 'gogogo(android.view.View)' is never used".